# Turn off "use template" query in emacs

Tags: emacs

How do you turn off the "use template" query for template.el in emacs? I tried `(setq template-initialize-query nil)` and it didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried:

```
(setq template-auto-insert t)
```